# If item in list a in list b

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have two lists. I need to write a function `detect` which

> a 'for item in list_a' loop to check if the item exists in list_b.

How would I go about doing this? *I can't find anything without appropriate keywords!*

```
list_a = ["Q", "W", "E"]
list_b = ["Q", "D", "E"]

def detect(item):
    return

detect(list_a[0])  
>>True
detect(list_a[1])
>>False
```

I have tried:

```
for item in list_a:
    if item in list_b:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Does not make any sense what you are asking. You want to know which items of two lists are in both lists?

Comment: are you off by 1? lists have a 0-based index

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> set_b = set(["Q", "D", "E"])
>>> set_a = set(["Q", "W", "E"])
>>> set_a.intersection(set_b)
set(['Q', 'E'])
>>> 'Q' in set_a.intersection(set_b)
True
>>> '42' in set_a.intersection(set_b)
False
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing calling it `list_a` when it is a set! (but I agree, sets are the way to do this)

Comment: this is a great solution, but i have my reservations about storing the items in sets, sometimes lists contain multiple times the same item for a specific reason, i think if you were to wrap the whole thing into a function that received two lists and returned their intersection also as a list - it would be a much more appeasing answer.

Answer (score 2):

To check whether an item is in the list or not, you can use `in` operator: -

```
"Q" in ["Q", "W", "R"]
>> True
```

Now, for each item in `list_a`, check whether it is in `list_b` or not. That will give you desired result.

Answer (score 1):

What you tried was almost right. Here's a corrected version:

```
def detect(item, list_a, list_b):
    for item in list_a:
        if item in list_b:
            return True
    return False  # not found
```

The problem with your version was that it only checked the first item in `list_a` and the returned either a `True` or `False` value. The modified version  keeps going until if finds something in both lists, or returns `False` only after it's checked everything in first list.

If you're going to call the function a lot, it can be optimized by creating and using `set`s instead of the one or both of the lists because the `in` operator works much faster on a `set` than on a `list`. However converting the list(s) to set(s) incurs some overhead, so it might not be worth the effort.